# Getting huge number after using simple subtraction in DAX measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-modeling

I'm kind of new to DAX and I'm basically learning as I'm using it in my work. We are building reports in PowerBI and we have data model that gets data from Oracle database. So I'm using DAX to create measures in this data model.

I need to substract 2 numbers from each other. So I created simple measure which looked like this:
[MEASURE1] - [MEASURE2]

Whether it works or it doesn't depends on my Period filter which uses another table. I don't know how could period be related to any of this. So when I change filter to some values, I get normal number. However, when I switch it to different values, I get numbers like 2,27483058473905E-13.

Weird thing is that if I check those two measures that I'm subtracting, they have exactly the same numbers, so the difference should be 0.

I know this is not the best explanation, but it is impossible to describe entire data model here. So I'm just looking for some ideas what could possibly be causing this and what should I check.

I have literally no idea what could be causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point precision.

Either use fixed decimal data types, specify the format string of the measure, or wrap your measure in `ROUND`, e.g.:

```
Diff =
ROUND (
    [Measure 1] - [Measure 2] ,
    2
)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying to my problem. So after a lot of googling I came across this decimal point precision topic. However, I still can't wrap my head around it and fully understand it. I'm using many calculations like this and I have never encountered this problem. 

Also, where are these numbers at 14+ decimal places coming from ? We are working with data that have 8-9 decimal places. Even in database I only see numbers with 9 decimal places. So there is no reason why any number should have numbers at 14+ decimal places.

Comment: Note that the effect is not due to decimal precision, but floating point precision in estimating decimal values based on bits, transferring binary arithmetic to base 10.

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but see the first few examples in [this article](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) on the same topic in Python. There the value `0.1` is actually estimated to some number that is very close to, but not actually equal to `0.1`.

Comment: I've read the article and to be honest, I still don't completely understand. English is not my mother tongue so it is harder to understand these math topics. If you could be so kind and explain to me like I'm five this: 

why 99% of numbers in my report are shown with 9 decimal places but this one (or big minority of numbers ) are displayed with like 20 decimal places? I'm sure there are many numbers that run into this issue of decimal to binary conversion but I don't see any other number having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

2,27483058473905E-13 is not a huge number, but as close as a decimal calculator can get to zero.